# Opera lost all data after autoupgrade to 102 on Windows 10 - how to recover it?

Tags: windows-10, updates, opera, data-loss-prevention

Today after laptop restart I noticed my seconday browser - Opera - autoupgraded, then it wasn't functional after startup - tabs were not connecting to websites. So I restarted it and noticed a huge issue.

Everything that I utilized was gone - cache, cookies, settings, extensions, recent tabs. I was logged out too.

How to recover data in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an awful bug of 102 version that apparently affects only "chosen" users.

On Opera forums I got linked to this helpful [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/operabrowser/comments/15znpg9/warning_upgrading_to_opera_102_might_cause_your/) that describes the issue and mentions potential fixes. One is rolling back to 101, which is more of a workaround.

The other one is what I recommend:

1. Close Opera.
2. For cache, navigate to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable`, then cut/copy everything inside except `Default` folder.
3. Paste everything to `Default` folder, overwrite when prompted.
4. For data, navigate to `%APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable` and backup the entire folder just in case. Then cut/copy everything inside except `Default` folder.
5. Paste everything to `Default` folder, overwrite when prompted.
6. Relaunch Opera and check if data is back.
7. If anything out of data is missing, close Opera again and try to recover missing parts individually, while deleting newer files that got created in `Default` directory after initial launch. E.g. for latest tabs I had to delete everything in `Sessions` folder and then recover older `Session_` and `Tabs_` files.

Everything that I needed came back.

Comment: Grim! Glad you got it.

Comment: You are a life saver my friend, worked find for me, lost open tabs, but you can restore those from history no problem.